# Not able to print the Invoice of orders from the admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice

[image: I am getting error whenever I tried to print the orders invoice from my admin panel , Please help me how to fix this !!]

I am getting error whenever I tried to print the **order's invoice** from my **admin panel** , Please help me how to fix this !!

```
#0 /home/revsho/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php(558): Mage::throwException('PDF total model...')
#1 /home/revsho/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php(579): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract->_getTotalsList(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#2 /home/revsho/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php(149): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract->insertTotals(Object(Zend_Pdf_Page), Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#3 /home/revsho/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Sales/Invoice.php(119): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice->getPdf(Array)
#4 /home/revsho/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php(489): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice->printAction()
#5 /home/revsho/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController->printAction()
#6 /home/revsho/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('print')
#7 /home/revsho/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /home/revsho/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /home/revsho/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /home/revsho/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not show the full error message. I assume some third party module is mentioned in the hidden part of the line #1.

The easiest (not the best) way is to disable this module (if any) and return default functionality.

Or you can give more information

Comment: @VenkateshCh did you add some custom total fees to the order?

Comment: No, I didn't add any thing.It's direct invoice from the customer.